# Bada and Flash 9 - can I create bada-desctop widget containing flash content?

Tags: html, flash, widget, bada

So web is full of articles on bada (1.2) not having fp9 or having only flash lite 4, or only 3.1... So wikipedia [talls us about full FP9 support.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bada_%28operating_system%29#Architecture) I wonder have any one trued to [create a widget](http://www.badadev.com/how-to-create-bada-widgets/) for Bada (1.2) with FP9 inside? Is it possible ore flash lite 3.1 is limit for widget?

Answer (score 0):

Though developing widgets for bada desktop is limited, you can develop live wallpaper or lock screen for bada w/ flash.

http://developer.bada.com/library/Live-Wallpaper-and-Lockscreen-development-using-Flash